# SpringBoot +Vue Project: Gradle Build Error

Tags: gradle

SpringBoot + Vue project, gradle build error:

Execution failed for task ':nodeSetup'.

> Could not find method layout() for arguments [pattern, com.moowork.gradle.node.task.SetupTask$_addRepository_closure5$_closure7@185cb06f] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultIvyArtifactRepository.

Answer (score 1):

**Cause**: There is a breaking change in gradle 6.8 which is you can checkout here:

> https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#configuring_the_layout_of_an_ivy_repository
>
> > "The 'layout' method taking a configuration block has been removed and is replaced by 'patternLayout'.

Check this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70662387/node-build-fail-after-upgrade-to-gradle-7-3).